# Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64

Tags: debugging, gdb, redhat, yum

I know this question is answered already in another thread, however I tried all the solutions given in the other thread including -

Searching for the package,
trying to install the package,
installing yum-utils 
and debuginfo-install glibc

Finally, I even set enabled=1 and gpgcheck=0 in redhat.repo under /etc/yum.repos.d, what else should be done for me to get rid of this error?

What I am trying to do is, debug a program(using gdb) with a shared object library. The program and .so file are both compiled on the same server(Redhat Maipo) and I am still seeing this error. I can't step through the code as a result - or are the two unrelated?

Answer (score 2):

> I am still seeing this error.

It isn't an error.

> I can't step through the code as a result - or are the two unrelated?

Which code are you trying to step through?

Missing `glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64` will only prevent you from stepping through GLIBC itself. Installing it will not help if the code you are trying to step through is the code you compiled yourself (which your question implies is exactly what you are trying to do).

Comment: I should have given a proper background to my question. This is my issue. We have a shared object library whose functionality I am not sure about. I do know that whenever any program that creates a file (a program with a simple touch command) is run after loading this shared object library, the created file has setuid or setgid permission set. This should not be happening. I was trying to debug the problem and find out why the library is introducing this error. I have the source code of the library and there is no code in it which changes the permissions of a file.

Comment: I tried compiling the library with debug symbols and then running the file creation program after loading the library, but I can't step through the library code. In fact I am getting a segmentation fault error if I load the library (with debug symbols). Without debug symbols I am unable to step through. I was under the impression that the missing package is a reason why I can't step through, that's why the post.

Comment: @user4002112 Instead of posting excessive comments, please *edit* your question. Also, you need to show *exactly* what you do and what results you observe. Saying "I tried <something> and it didn't work" isn't going to allow anyone to help you.