# What can I do differently after I install those missing debug info packages for gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have a fresh install `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`, and `gdb` verison is `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-119.el7`.

I saw the Missing separate debuginfos warning

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
```

and I learnt that:

> Missing `glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64` will only prevent you from stepping through `GLIBC` itself.

from this answer [Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991699/5983841).

---

Now I've succeeded installing all those debug infos pacakges. But I can't see a difference. What are the **additionals things** that I can do now with those extra packages installed?

Take this C++ program as an example:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
        vector<int> b = {4,5,6};
        map<int, vector<int>> m = {{1, a}, {2, b}};
        cout << m[1][0] << endl;
        cout << m[2][0] << endl;
}
```

compile with `g++ -Wall -g test.cpp -std=c++11`.

I can **step through** `libstdc++` both before and after installing those debug info packages. So what's the difference?

What I understand **step through** is that for example when I press `s` at this line `cout << m[1][0] << endl;`,  `gdb` shows that I am in `stl_map.h:481` :

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::operator[](int&&) (this=0x7fffffffe3f0, 
    __k=<unknown type in /root/a.out, CU 0x0, DIE 0x7b70>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_map.h:481
481     iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
```

related question: [Missing separate debuginfos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148652/missing-separate-debuginfos)

---

**Solution Update:**

I figured out the details after reading this [How to use debug version of libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000335/how-to-use-debug-version-of-libc). I also read about how [separate debug info files work](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) and tried manually redirecting `gdb` to find source files with `set substitute-path` by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c/48287761#48287761).

And eventually I learn how the things work together:

1. By default those shared libraries don't have debug info embedded in the `.so`
2. And the debug infos are stored in another directory where `gdb` would try to load from.
3. Beyond that, I still need the source text files to `list` around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what's the difference?

The difference is that you can now list sources of GLIBC (which is not the same as `libstdc++`) and step though them.

Try `(gdb) list abort` with and without `debuginfo-install`.

**Update:**

> Am I able to "list soucre of libstdc++" and "step through them" without those packages?

`libstdc++` is different from GLIBC in that significant portion of its functionality is provided by *templates*, which are included into your own sources. When you step through e.g. `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_map.h`, that is *exactly* what's happening.

But you may still need to `debuginfo-install libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64` to be able to list and step though parts of `libstdc++` which are *not* part of the provided headers.

IIRC, implementation of `std::basic_string<char, ...>` and various parts of `std::basic_ios` fall into that category. You can run `nm -C libstdc++.so.6 | egrep ' [TW] '` to see a list of such symbols.

**Update 2:**

> Are those installed debug infos just glibc and gcc soure text files?

No.

The debug info is a set of files which allows debugger to associate a particular offset into the `.text` of the library with the source code that produced machine code at that offset. It also encodes types of parameters and variables, location of local variables within a given function, and more. You can read more about debug info [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information).

On *some* systems, debug info package *also* includes the source of the library, but that isn't universal across Linux systems, and isn't the *main* purpose of the debug info package (you can install *source* package if all you wanted are the sources).

Comment: Ok. I am going to install a new CentOS 7.2 on my VPS and try what you said. But allow me ask a question ahead, so installing the debuginfo packages is all about allowing me to list sources of GLIBC and step through them. Then why is it asking me to install `debuginfo-install libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64`, which is related to `c++`?  Am I able to "list soucre of libstdc++" and "step through them" without those packages? (As shown in my question, when I can see I am in `stl_map.h`, that mean I can step through `libstdc++` right? Sorry I am not that sure. :))

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Check my answer see if I get anything wrong. :P Thank you again!

Comment: Are those installed debug infos just glibc  and gcc soure text files? I was playing around with some test programs with `g++` , `-g` set and not, and now I am having a feeling that what I install from `debuginfo-install` are just source text files `.c`.

Comment: I figured out the details after reading this [How to use debug version of libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000335/how-to-use-debug-version-of-libc) question answered by you. I also read about how separate debug info files work and tried manually redirecting `gdb` to find source files with `set substitute-path` by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48287761/5983841).

Comment: So eventually I learn how the things work together:
 By default those shared libraries don't have debug info embedded in and the debug infos are stored in another directory where `gdb` would try to load from. Beyond that, I still need the source text files to `list` around.

Comment: May I ask you one last question related to this post? I opened a new question and I am curious about [Why debug files of libstdc++ are installed via glibc-debuginfo and gcc-debuginfo but not something called libstdc++-debuginfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068241/why-debug-files-of-libstdc-are-installed-via-glibc-debuginfo-and-gcc-debuginfo)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Employed Russian's answer, now I know the exact differences.

Here's what I observe from 2 fresh install CentOS 7.2, one with debug info installed, one is not.

OS version: `CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)`

GDB version: `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-119.el7`

Test program:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        string s = "123";
        vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
        vector<int> b = {4,5,6};
        map<int, vector<int>> m = {{1, a}, {2, b}};
        cout << m[1][0] << endl;
        cout << m[2][0] << endl;
        cout << s << endl;
        abort();
        //raise(3);
}
```

---

1. I installed the debug packages by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65031770/5983841)

And by running

```
debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
```

I saw those packages get installed.

```
========================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch              Version                      Repository            Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc-debuginfo                                x86_64            4.8.5-44.el7                 debuginfo            195 M
 glibc-debuginfo                              x86_64            2.17-307.el7.1               debuginfo            9.5 M
 nss-softokn-debuginfo                        x86_64            3.44.0-8.el7_7               debuginfo            2.1 M
 yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info            noarch            1.1.31-54.el7_8              os                    29 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gcc-base-debuginfo                           x86_64            4.8.5-44.el7                 debuginfo            2.9 M
 glibc-debuginfo-common                       x86_64            2.17-307.el7.1               debuginfo            9.7 M
```

It's interested that there is no something like `libstdc++-debuginfo` got installed, though `libstdc++` shows in the "Missing separate debug info warnings". **Could someone explain?**

---

2. On both servers, I compiled the test program with `g++ -g -Wall test.cpp -std=c++11` and run `gdb ./a.out`

- `b main`, `r`.

On the server that installs the debug info, I can step into `string s = "123";` ,`abort`
and just look around. On the other server, it just step over the line(act like pressing `n`) when I press `s`.

Server that install the debug infos:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:10
10          string s = "123";
(gdb) s
std::allocator<char>::allocator (this=0x7fffffffe45b)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocator.h:113
113       allocator() throw() { }
(gdb) s
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x7fffffffe450, 
    __s=0x403b73 "123", __a=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:212
212     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
(gdb) s
```

---

```
16          cout << s << endl;
(gdb) n
123
17      abort();
(gdb) s
__GI_abort () at abort.c:52
52  {
(gdb) list
47  
48  
49  /* Cause an abnormal program termination with core-dump.  */
50  void
51  abort (void)
52  {
53    struct sigaction act;
54    sigset_t sigs;
55  
56    /* First acquire the lock.  */
```

And that's the differences.