# Why debug files of libstdc++ are installed via glibc-debuginfo and gcc-debuginfo but not something called libstdc++-debuginfo?

Tags: gdb, glibc, libstdc++

When I was trying to figuring out this question [What can I do differently after I install those missing debug info packages for gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031982/what-can-i-do-differently-after-i-install-those-missing-debug-info-packages-for) asked by myself, I noticed that when I try to install the `libstdc++` debug infos (test distro is `CentOS 7.2`):

```
debuginfo-install libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
```

What the system is going to install are:

```
[root@VM-0-17-centos debug]# debuginfo-install libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
debuginfo                                                                                        | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
debuginfo/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                    | 2.5 MB  00:00:02     
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc-debuginfo.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gcc-base-debuginfo = 4.8.5-44.el7 for package: gcc-debuginfo-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
---> Package glibc-debuginfo.x86_64 0:2.17-307.el7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-debuginfo-common = 2.17-307.el7.1 for package: glibc-debuginfo-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64
---> Package yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info.noarch 0:1.1.31-54.el7_8 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc-base-debuginfo.x86_64 0:4.8.5-44.el7 will be installed
---> Package glibc-debuginfo-common.x86_64 0:2.17-307.el7.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch              Version                      Repository            Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc-debuginfo                                x86_64            4.8.5-44.el7                 debuginfo            195 M
 glibc-debuginfo                              x86_64            2.17-307.el7.1               debuginfo            9.5 M
 yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info            noarch            1.1.31-54.el7_8              os                    29 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gcc-base-debuginfo                           x86_64            4.8.5-44.el7                 debuginfo            2.9 M
 glibc-debuginfo-common                       x86_64            2.17-307.el7.1               debuginfo            9.7 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+2 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 217 M
Installed size: 1.0 G
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
```

---

**My question is:**

Why `libstdc++` debug infos(files) are installed via `glibc` debug infos? As I know, `glibc` is the GNU implemetation of standard C library. How would that relate to `libstdc++` which is a `C++` thing? I expect something called `libstdc++-debuginfo` to show on the list :)

Comment: Your question appears to be backwards: you aren't installing `glibc-debuginfo` and ending up with `libstdc++` debug info installed (as the question title suggests), but the opposite seems to be happening.

Comment: @EmployedRussian So `libstdc++` doesn't have its own packages and is included in `glibc-debuginfo`? I don't get the sense. They are 2 different libraries.  Anyway, this might not be a important question.

Comment: It looks like on CentOS 7, the debuginfo (and source code) for libstdc++,  libgomp,libquadmath, libiberty, and a few other small libraries are provided by the `gcc-base-debuginfo` and `gcc-debuginfo` packages. I haven't seen an explanation for this. Maybe they're all needed to debug gcc and it was convenient to put them all in two large packages.